# Arrow flip when dropdown opens JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written code which allows a user to click on a div to open a dropdown menu of radio buttons. I am trying to get the arrows to rotate 180* once the dropdown menus open, and to rotate back 180* when dropdown menu closes. I wrote a couple lines of code inside the current code block. I believe to be close to solving it. Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you! Will upload html, css, and js.

```
<main class="subscription__container">
        <section
          id="preferences"
          class="subscription__container--preferences box"
        >
          <div class="question__container">
            <h3 class="question__container--title">
              How do you drink your coffee?
            </h3>
            <img
              class="question__container--img"
              src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
              alt="arrow"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options__container">
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="capsule"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Capsule"
                value="Capsule"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="capsule">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="filter"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Filter"
                value="Filter"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="filter">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="espresso"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Espresso"
                value="Espresso"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="espresso">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful
                  experience.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="bean" class="subscription__container--beans box">
          <div class="question__container">
            <h3 class="question__container--title">What type of coffee?</h3>
            <img
              class="question__container--img"
              src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
              alt="arrow"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options__container">
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="single"
                type="radio"
                data-bean="Single"
                value="Single"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="single">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Single Origin</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Distinct, high quality coffee from a specific family-owned
                  farm.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="decaf"
                type="radio"
                data-bean="Decaf"
                value="Decaf"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="decaf">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Decaf</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Just like regular coffee, except the caffeine has been
                  removed.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="blended"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Blended"
                value="Blended"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="blended">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Blended</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Combination of two or three dark roasted beans of organic
                  coffees.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

```
.question__container--img.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```
//
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".question__container--img");
[...questionBox].forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
    arrows.classList.toggle("rotate");
  })
);
//
```

At the moment, the console reads back.. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `arrows` contains a list of all `.question__container--img` elements, not a single one.
What you need is get the `arrow` from `el`, not `document`:

```js
//
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
[...questionBox].forEach((el) =>
{
  const arrow = el.querySelector(".question__container--img");
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
    arrow.classList.toggle("rotate");
  })
});
//
```

```css
.question__container--img.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
        <section
          id="preferences"
          class="subscription__container--preferences box"
        >
          <div class="question__container">
            <h3 class="question__container--title">
              How do you drink your coffee?
            </h3>
            <img
              class="question__container--img"
              src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
              alt="arrow"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options__container">
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="capsule"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Capsule"
                value="Capsule"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="capsule">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="filter"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Filter"
                value="Filter"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="filter">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="espresso"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Espresso"
                value="Espresso"
                name="preferences"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="espresso">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful
                  experience.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="bean" class="subscription__container--beans box">
          <div class="question__container">
            <h3 class="question__container--title">What type of coffee?</h3>
            <img
              class="question__container--img"
              src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
              alt="arrow"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options__container">
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="single"
                type="radio"
                data-bean="Single"
                value="Single"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="single">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Single Origin</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Distinct, high quality coffee from a specific family-owned
                  farm.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="decaf"
                type="radio"
                data-bean="Decaf"
                value="Decaf"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="decaf">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Decaf</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Just like regular coffee, except the caffeine has been
                  removed.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="options__container--option">
              <input
                id="blended"
                type="radio"
                data-preference="Blended"
                value="Blended"
                name="beanType"
              />
              <label class="test__trail" for="blended">
                <h4 class="options__container--title">Blended</h4>
                <p class="options__container--description">
                  Combination of two or three dark roasted beans of organic
                  coffees.
                </p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling rotate, you can change its transform instead using jQuery:

```
$("whatever").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
```

Or using vanilla Javascript:

```
whatever.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
```

And then change it back when it opens.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could change `arrows.classList.toggle("rotate");` to `arrows.style.transform = "rotate(180/0)";`  by using if/else.

Also you can add `display:` to your subMenu css then use `subMenu.style.display = "none/block";` again by if/else.